# JUNIT Test with string parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage

I'm a beginner and i'm writing unittests and I've stumbled across something I can't find a solution for that fits my needs.

I want to write some Junit Test for that exceptions.

There is my class with my Method

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
 * CustomerInfo
 */
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-02-21T07:51:10.135Z[GMT]")

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class CustomerInfo   {
  @JsonProperty("LsId")
  @Size(max=40)
  private String lsId = null;

  @JsonProperty("SocialReason")
  @Size(max=100)
  private String socialReason = null;

  @JsonProperty("NationalId")
  @Size(max=40)
  private String nationalId = null;

  public CustomerInfo lsId(String lsId) {
    this.lsId = lsId;
    return this;
  }

  public CustomerInfo socialReason(String socialReason) {
    this.socialReason = socialReason;
    return this;
  }

  public CustomerInfo nationalId(String nationalId) {
    this.nationalId = nationalId;
    return this;
  }
}
```

and my testClass :

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;

class CustomerInfoTest {
    
    
    CustomerInfo customInfo = new CustomerInfo();

    @Before(value = "")
    public void setUp() {
        customInfo.setLsId("6485");
        customInfo.setSocialReason("banque de france");
        customInfo.setNationalId("54865");
    }
    
    @Test
    void testLsId() {
        assertEquals(customInfo, customInfo.lsId("4852"));
    }

    @Test
    void testSocialReason() {
        assertEquals(customInfo, customInfo.socialReason("bank"));
    }

    @Test
    void testNationalId() {
        assertEquals(customInfo, customInfo.nationalId("4852"));
    }

}
```

My tests pass but my coverage is average 30% with that, do you have some better ideas ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hint to the code coverage provider that some code has been geenrated and should be excluded from coverage, lombok can do this by adding a generated annotation; if you configure

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I would also like to test the code generated with lombok

Comment: I mean, you could test the getters/setters toString, but personally What value would that provide?